# Object result with values in its property becomes undefined when I try to access them

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

[image]

Hello girls and boys, I have a probleme accessing the value of my object's property.
It says that My properties are undefined, which I know they re not.

I just do an http get request with angular , I receive data, but once I try to access the value, in the console it says the properties are undefined;

here is the code :

```
this.globalService.getClientEmployee(this.currentUserID).subscribe(
    (data) => { 

       this.clientEmployee = data;

        console.log(this.clientEmployee);

        const accessClient = this.clientEmployee.AccessClient;
        const accessDepartment = this.clientEmployee.AccessDepartment;
      if (!accessClient || !accessDepartment) {
        this.showMyRequests = false;
      } else if (data.AccessClient && data.AccessDepartment){
        this.showMyRequests = true;
      }
```

the console.log(this.clientEmployee) :

> {id: 53, clientId: 255, personId: 53, clientEmployeeTypeId: null, clientDepartmentId: null, …}
> accessClient: true
> accessDepartment:true
> changeClient:true
> changeDepartment:true
> clientDepartmentId:null
> clientEmployeeTypeId:null
> clientId:255
> communicationLanguageId:null
> copyProject:false
> costCenter:null
> id: 53
> isAdminClientPortal: true
> isGroupAdmin: false
> num: null
> personId: 53
> tenantId: null
> [[Prototype]]: Object

So as you can see the properties I try to acess have values.
So what the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Maybe AccessClient > accessClient? Js is case sensitive.

Comment: You would have caught that if you would have used the power of typescript btw.. 

Comment: Do you meant the console log statement in the function is not working, or attempting to log `this.clientEmployee` outside of this function fails? If that's the latter, you're running into an async issue.

Comment: MikeOne your were close ! I solved it thanks to you. I had defined a type return which was recovering the data's property names. I just 'any' as return type and modified the casing  of the property and that worked ! thank you !